# How can I ensure I have only one instance of a PHP script running via Apache?

Tags: php, apache

I have an `index.php` script that I use as a post-commit URL on a Google Code site.  This script clones a directory and builds a project that may take some work.  I want to avoid having this script running more than one time in parallel.

Is there a mechanism I can use to avoid executing that script if another one is already in session?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use [flock](http://php.net/flock) with `LOCK_EX` to gain an exclusive lock on a file.

E.g.:

```
<?php
$fp = fopen('/tmp/php-commit.lock', 'r+');
if (!flock($fp, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB)) {
    exit;
}

// ... do stuff

fclose($fp);
?>
```

For PHP versions after 5.3.2 you need to manually release the lock using 
    flock($fp, LOCK_UN);

Comment: @LongEars Mention this code actually runs another instance on Windows, as `LOCK_NB` doesn't work there according to PHP manual on `flock`. It will wait on `flock` until previous instances finish, and then will run the whole code.

Comment: Also, to ensure this works as expected you may want to change the fopen mode to:
`$fp = fopen('/tmp/php-commit.lock', 'c');
`
Using 'r+' would throw a PHP error if the commit.lock file does not already exist.

Comment: what happens when php script crashes, i.e. throws exception, without doing fclose ? can then another instance starts ?

Comment: For AMB, the operating system is in charge of cleaning it up for you ON SCRIPT TERMINATION (not on fclose).

Answer (score 2):

how long does it take to run.

could use memcache

```
<?php
$m = new Memcache(); // check the constructor call

if( $m->get( 'job_running' ) ) exit;

else $m->set( 'job_running', true );



//index code here

//at the end of the script

$m->delete( 'job_running' );

?>
```

If the task fails you will need to clear from memcache. Flock is a good option too... probably better actually.

Comment: To avoid manual clearing on task failure, you could just use a time-limit for the set according to some top boundary of the task running time.

Answer (score 1):

Only if you save the state of the running script and check when the script starts if an other script is currently active.

For example to save if a script is running you could do something like this:

```
$state = file_get_contents('state.txt');

if (!$state) {
   file_put_contents('state.txt', 'RUNNING, started at '.time());

   // Do your stuff here...

   // When your stuff is finished, empty file
   file_put_contents('state.txt', '');
}
```